# Android Studio 4.1 Plugin Error: Plugin "Parcelable Code Generator(for kotlin)" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried to install the plugin Parcelable Code Generator(for kotlin) in Android Studio 4.1, but I faced this error. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Encountering same issues with this and other plugins in latest Android Studio 4.1. Not sure why this question was closed though, how could you "focus" this question any further... It's already about a specific plugin for a specific version of Android Studio. It's already ultra focused.

Comment: FWIW, I figured out how to fix it by manually deleting the plugin jar via this path: C:\Users\*username*\AppData\Roaming\Google\AndroidStudio4.1\plugins, then using the "Install Plugin from Disk" option to re-install the plugin jar. Now it works again.

Comment: And nevermind, sort of. That approach only works for the current session. If you close Android Studio and reload it, it will spit out the same errors as before. Seems you have to manually uninstall and reinstall every launch of Android Studio. Frustrating.

Comment: Why is the issues closed then??

Comment: **Create Parcelable class without plugin in Android Studio**
Implements Parcelable in your class and then put cursor on "implements Parcelable" and hit Alt+Enter and select Add Parcelable implementation. 
That's it. 
[Screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbGOs.png)

Comment: @VijayDesai This creates the necessary methods, but not the actual code for writing/reading the fields' data to/form the parcel.

Comment: @Ridcully Who said it doesn't, Sure it does create "writeToParcel" and constructor for Parcel in.

Comment: @VijayDesai yes but writeToParcel() is empty. With the plugin, I could selext the fields to be parcelized, and it would create all the code, including writing field values into parcel and restore from parcel.

Comment: There is a work around for it, Use Java code for generating Parcelable where it creates everything and then you can turn the class to Kotlin.